# sklearn pipeline is not working

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, sentiment-analysis

I am new to sklearn pipeline and studying about it from sklearn documentation. I used it in sentiment analysis on [movie review](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/pabo/movie-review-data/) data. Data contains two columns, first `class` and second `text`.

```
input_file_df = pd.read_csv("movie-pang.csv")
x_train = input_file_df["text"] #used complete data as train data
y_train = input_file_df["class"]
```

I used only one feature, `sentiment score for each sentence.` I wrote custom transformer for this:

```
class GetWorldLevelSentiment(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

def __init__(self):
    pass

def get_word_level_sentiment(self, word_list):
    sentiment_score = 1
    for word in word_list:
        word_sentiment = swn.senti_synsets(word)

        if len(word_sentiment) > 0:
            word_sentiment = word_sentiment[0]
        else:
            continue

        if word_sentiment.pos_score() > word_sentiment.neg_score():
            word_sentiment_score = word_sentiment.pos_score()
        elif word_sentiment.pos_score() < word_sentiment.neg_score():
            word_sentiment_score = word_sentiment.neg_score()*(-1)
        else:
            word_sentiment_score = word_sentiment.pos_score()

        print word, " " , word_sentiment_score
        if word_sentiment_score != 0:
            sentiment_score = sentiment_score * word_sentiment_score

    return sentiment_score

def transform(self, review_list, y=None):
    sentiment_score_list = list()
    for review in review_list:
        sentiment_score_list.append(self.get_word_level_sentiment(review.split()))
    
    return np.asarray(sentiment_score_list)

def fit(self, x, y=None):
    return self
```

Pipeline which I used is:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
("word_level_sentiment",GetWorldLevelSentiment()),
("clf", MultinomialNB())])
```

and then call fit on pipeline:

```
pipeline.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

But this is giving following error to me:

`This MultinomialNB instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method.`

Can someone please guide me what I am doing wrong here ?? It will be a great help.

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace of error and complete code to duplicate the behaviour.

Comment: Try to remove parentheses like this: ("clf", MultinomialNB)

Comment: @CrazyElf . Removing parenthesis will not work. Pipeline requires an instance, not class.

Comment: Oh, yes. Need to instantiate.

Comment: @sdream, can you link the original csv file used. The link you gave is not useful.

Comment: Your `review_list` parameter in your transform method should be `X`, and your `x` parameter in your fit method should be `X`. Also, what is swn in `swn.senti_synsets(word)`?

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr Most possibly:- `from nltk.corpus import sentiwordnet as swn`

Comment: @VivekKumar thanks for replying. I searched but could not found direct link for csv file. I followed the given link and in the section `sentiment polarity dataset`, I downloaded polarity_dataset_v2.0.

Comment: I am still not able to get the csv `"movie-pang.csv"` , which you are using. Anyways, I tested with my data and there are multiple mistakes in your code. First the `transform()` method is returning a row vector which is not right. Change it to `return np.asarray(sentiment_score_list).reshape(len(review_list), -1)`. Second, the sentiment score can be negative, which is not allowed in MultinomialNB.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr The parameter names doesnt matter as long as position is correct.

Comment: @VivekKumar that's true, but for the purposes of intent and following sklearn's custom transformer conventions, it's better to use `X`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
class GetWorldLevelSentiment(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

def __init__(self):
    pass

def get_word_level_sentiment(self, word_list):
    sentiment_score = 1
    for word in word_list:
        word_sentiment = swn.senti_synsets(word)

        if len(word_sentiment) > 0:
            word_sentiment = word_sentiment[0]
        else:
            continue

        if word_sentiment.pos_score() > word_sentiment.neg_score():
            word_sentiment_score = word_sentiment.pos_score()
        elif word_sentiment.pos_score() < word_sentiment.neg_score():
            word_sentiment_score = word_sentiment.neg_score()*(-1)
        else:
            word_sentiment_score = word_sentiment.pos_score()

        print word, " " , word_sentiment_score
        if word_sentiment_score != 0:
            sentiment_score = sentiment_score * word_sentiment_score

    return sentiment_score

def transform(self, review_list, y=None):
    sentiment_score_list = list()
    for review in review_list:
        sentiment_score_list.append(self.get_word_level_sentiment(review.split()))

    return pandas.DataFrame(sentiment_score-list)

def fit(self, x, y=None):
    return self
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn import metrics
import pandas as pd

# Текстовый трансформатор
class TextTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """
    Преобразование текстовых признаков
    """
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def fit(self, X, y=None, *parg, **kwarg):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.key]

# Числовой трансформатор
class NumberTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """
    Преобразование числовых признаков
    """
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X[[self.key]]



def fit_predict(model, X_train, X_test, y_train):
    # использовать частотный векторизатор обратной частоты документа, 
    vec_tdidf = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,3), max_df=0.93, min_df=0.05)

    #Текстовый признак clean 
    text = Pipeline([
                    ('transformer', TextTransformer(key='clear_text')),
                    ('vectorizer', vec_tdidf)
                    ])
    #Числовой признак word_clean_count
    word_numeric = Pipeline([
                    ('transformer', NumberTransformer(key='word_count'))
                    ])

    posting_day = Pipeline([
                    ('transformer', NumberTransformer(key='posting_day'))
                    ])
    posting_month = Pipeline([
                    ('transformer', NumberTransformer(key='posting_month'))
                    ])
    post_theme = Pipeline([
                    ('transformer', NumberTransformer(key='theme'))
                    ])
    # Объединение всех признаков
    features = FeatureUnion([('Text_Feature', text),
                             ('Num1_Feature', word_numeric),
                             ('Num3_Feature', posting_day),
                             ('Num4_Feature', posting_month),
                             ('Num6_Feature', post_theme)

                            ])

    # Классификатор
    clf = model

    # Объединение классификатора и признаков
    pipe = Pipeline([('features', features),
                     ('clf',clf)
                     ])

    # Обучение модели
    pipe_fit=pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # Предсказание данных
    preds = pipe_fit.predict(X_test)

    return preds, pipe_fit
```